# Java client/server - sending multiple strings over a Socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a program `Client` that sends the server the string `LISTALL`.
After that, the server needs to check for all running processes on the system (Linux) using the `ps -e` command, and then return the result to the client.
Obviously the result is composed of multiple strings, so how can i get the client to receive and store them all?

Right now, this is what i get from the client:

`Message sent to the server: LISTALL
Message received from the server: null`

And from the server:

`Server started and listening to..
Message received from client: LISTALL`

And then it lists the results from the `ps -e` command as expected.

My code:

**Server:**

```
public class Server
{

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            int port = 25000;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");

            //Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop
            while(true)
            {
                //Reading the message from the client
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String list = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message received from client is "+list);


                //Sending the response back to the client.
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                String returnMessage;
                try
                {
                    ProcessBuilder build = new ProcessBuilder("ps", "-e");
                    Process proc = build.start();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                    returnMessage=reader.readLine();
                          bw.write(returnMessage);

                    proc.waitFor();

                    System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
                    bw.flush();}
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    //Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
                    returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class Client
{

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 25000;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            String list = "LISTALL";

            String sendMessage = list + "\n";
            bw.write(sendMessage);
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while (br.readLine() != null) {         
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
        }}
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Closing the socket
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your read loops are incorrect. They should be of the general form:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // Do something with `line`
}
```

At present you are throwing away every odd line, and printing a null if there is an odd number of lines.

Comment: For some reason i still get the same output from the client. That is, instead of outputting `Message received from server: ....` followed by the correct output, it says `Message received from server: null`.

Comment: Only if you didn't execute this code. With this code, it's impossible, as you can see for yourself. NB You have this mistake in two places.

Comment: So i have to make the same fix in the write loop?

Comment: You have to make the same fix everywhere you have perpetrated the same mistake. I don't see any write loop. You also need to close the sockets.

Comment: Sorry i meant the Client's read loop. I fixed both the Client and Server read loops but it gives me the same result still.

Comment: Post the updated code. Make sure you're not calling `readLine()` twice where you only _want_ to call it once, otherwise you'll eat the first line and then operate on the second line (which is probably null in your case). I suggest you review the `readLine()` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()).

Comment: If your loops call `readLine()` as indicated above, and *only* as indicated above, you cannot possibly get a null. You have made a transcription error.